# Order of verses in Quran

Tags: quran, surah, verses

I wonder how the verses are ordered in Quran. Looking at this [site](http://www.islam-info.ch/en/Arrangement_of_the_Quran.htm), it says all verses were ordered in the life time of the prophet, because Quran was being written and was in same order we read today. This [site](http://www.missionislam.com/quran/revealationorder.htm) also mentions that the prophet used to recite Quran during prayer in correct order. But then there are these verses in which the verse that abrogates the previous verse are right after each other. For example [58:12-13](http://quran.com/58/12-13)

> O you who have believed, when you [wish to] privately consult the
>   Messenger, present before your consultation a charity. That is better
>   for you and purer. But if you find not [the means] - then indeed,
>   Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.58-12
>
> Have you feared to present before your consultation charities? Then
>   when you do not and Allah has forgiven you, then [at least] establish
>   prayer and give zakah and obey Allah and His Messenger. And Allah is
>   Acquainted with what you do.58-13

Supposedly there were number of days in the above two verse because people stopped coming to the prophet and then the second verse was revealed. Other times the verse that abrogates the previous verse lies far apart from the original verse. When it comes to the last verse of the Quran, it is still not clear. Among the many candidates for the last verse according to this [site](http://www.quranicstudies.com/quran/the-last-verse-of-the-quran/), many of the verses are not the last verses of the Surah, that proves, the verses order was not in the same order it was revealed.

Can someone clarify this? How were the verses ordered in the Quran? Was it determined by the prophet himself or was it done later in the first caliph period. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is not a complete agreement in this regard among scholars. There is t opinion: some say Prophet (SAWW) himself when was alive changed the arrange of verses from "ordered by revelation time" to current arrange by command of Allah and before this change of arrange order of verses was by revelation times.

And other opinion says after prophet Sahaba changed the arrange of verses of Quran.

The second opinion is considered much more correct by Shia scholars. For example the paper below ([Newest theory about arrange of verses of Quran](http://www.al-shia.org/html/far/books/majalat/28/01/02.htm)) proves the second opinion based on different evidences.

Also the Great Shia scholar and Quran scientist [Allamah Muhammad Husayn Tabatabaei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Husayn_Tabatabaei)
writer of [tafseer Al-Mizan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir_al-Mizan) was supporter of second opinion

But it is authentic that the Prophet (SAWW) ordered to Imam Ali a.s. that write the Quran bases on revelation time. and he did this duty after death of prophet until 6 months and remained at home for this duty and collected Quran written in different parts of animal skins and bone of animals and made it as a one book that he transported it by Camel and took it to mosque of the Prophet (SAWW) and said to Sahaba: this is Quran of prophet and I collected it. Sahaba said him: we have our own Quran and do not need it. Imam replied: you will never see it. Also when Imam Mahdi a.s. comes from Occultation will bring Quran of Imam Ali a.s. and will declare it as official Quran.

Currently there are verses with parts revealed in different times.

---

**References**

[Different Arrangements of Quran](http://www.al-islam.org/encyclopedia/chapter8/2.html)

The article [Newest theory about arrange of verses of Quran](http://www.al-shia.org/html/far/books/majalat/28/01/02.htm) from [Ahl ul-Bayt center](http://www.al-shia.org) under supervision of [Grand Ayatollah Sistani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_al-Sistani)

The valuable textbook [Quranic Scienses](http://www.hawzah.net/per/k/olm-qrn/index.htm)

Comment: Can you support your answer with evidences, you say "But it is authentic that the....." where is the proof ?